# Speeding up jQuery/Javascript search function

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, search

I have a list of over 3000 items with unique names. They are all wrapped inside UL tag like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"> Item_ID125167</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Item_ID146324</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then I have a search input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="searchfield" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <button type="submit" id="searchButton" onclick="filterByName()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
</span>
```

And finally a function to hide/show the matching items:

```
function filterByName() {
  $("li").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).children('a').text().toUpperCase().indexOf($("#searchfield").val().toUpperCase()) > -1) {
      $(this).css('display', "");
    } else {
      $(this).css('display', "none");
    }
  });
}
```

This feels kind of slow with over 3000 items while using oldish android phone. Is there a better solution for the search function?

Comment: Use find() instead of children(). Find uses native browser functionality and is usually faster.

Comment: My advice is do not show all 3000 items on single page but split them into pages (pagination technique) so that each page will show 50-100 items. By doing this you significantly reduce overhead of looping and greatly boost up performance. In practice, nobody is willing to scroll to see a long list anyway, that's why all online shopping websites they utilize pagination technique

Comment: Is the search still able to picks items quickly from lets say page 20 of the pagination?

Comment: It is supposed to be performed in server side. You have 3000 items on server and when someone goes search for a particular item by name, that name will be looked on server with 3000 items already there and return result to display in browser

Comment: This technique is implemented every where (Google, Ebay, Amazon...) so all you need to do is send request to server, let server do filter work then return results to you and you display those results in browser, simple and fast

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was thinking about this earlier but then I started to doubt is it really faster. But ill try with the server side trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

speeding it up means you should reuse resources as much as possible

```
var $list = {}; // initialize an empty global scope variable to keep your elements in
function filterByName(searchString) {
  //reusing $list will prefent you from walking the dom each time
  $list.each(function(index, el) {
    el.style.display = el.title.indexOf(searchString) > -1 ? "list-item" : "none";
  });
}

function loadList() {
  $list = $('#results').find('li'); //faster than $('#results > li');
  $list.each(function(index, el) {
      //save the uppercase search values in a propery to search faster
      //this saves you from running .toUpperCase() on every search
      var text = el.textContent || el.innerText;
      el.setAttribute('title', text.trim().toUpperCase()); //using title makes a faster search later
      $list[index]=el;
  }); 
}

$(function() {
    loadList();
  $('#searchButton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //prepariung the search sring here saves processing during search
    filterByName($("#searchfield").val().trim().toUpperCase());
    return false;
  });
  //if your list is build dynamicly simple run loadList() every time changes to the list content may happen
});
```

see a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/q1x7ujex/

Comment: I went with this and it's about 4x faster now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I tested `find` will work faster than `children` in this case.
You can run it by your self with [Test selectors](https://jsperf.com/jquery-selectors-context/2), or look at the results:[image].

If you don't feel any improvement in your eyes, you can see the results using the `console.time` I added to your function, It will log the time the operation took to the browser.

```
function filterByName() {
 //Instead of selecting the search field + getting it's value + toUpperCase 
 //*3000 times this way it will only happen once.
 var searchVal = $("#searchfield").val().toUpperCase();

//measures the time it takes for the operation
 console.time("test");
 $("li").each(function() {

    //find is faster than children
    if ($(this).find("a").text().toUpperCase().indexOf(searchVal >-1)) {
        this.style.display = '';
    } else {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
//Will write to the console the time it the operation took.
console.timeEnd("test");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! These were some new info for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will be working a little bit faster then your's. Try it

```
function filterByName() {
    var searchVal = $("#searchfield").val.toUpperCase();
    $("li").each(function() {
        if (this.children[0].textContent.toUpperCase().match(searchVal)) {
            this.style.display = '';
        } else {
            this.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Feels same speed. I think it's the DOM operation show/hide that is taking so long.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with this page: https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/

You've to use `find` instead of `children` (it says super-fast)

Other thing you can do is to create an array from that list and use [jQuery.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: I switched to find, but feels same speed still :/

Comment: You made uppercase operation over strings ... You would create a protptype for case-insensitive indexof

Comment: what? I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: He means you are first uppercasing every text and then compare. It would be faster if you have a similar function like indexOf which doesn't care about case-sensitiveness

Comment: I need to have case-sensitive item names